# Why excel quartile value is not matching with statistically defined calculation value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Let's say I want to calculate quartile 1 for the data set

```
1
2
4
7
8
9
10
12
```

So,MS execel 2016 will calculate quartile 1=QUARTILE(AB1:AB8,1), which will give me 3.5

Statistically Quartile 1 is the median of 1st half of the ordered data set. 1st half of the ordered data is 1,2,4,7. So Quartile 1=(2+4)/2=3

Comment: I'm also a bit puzzled here. `QUARTILE()` should work as `QUARTILE.INC()` meaning the mean of an even-numbered range should be included (7,5) and therefor the mean of the 1st quartile should actually be 4 >> `{1,2,4,7,7.5}`. I therefor deleted my answer.

Comment: A full treatment of the topic is [here](https://peltiertech.com/comparison/) (forward to "Techniques Used by Software Packages"; the exact methods are described in other articles in the series). The short of it is that Excel's approach to quartiles (N-1 interpolation, further described [here](https://peltiertech.com/quartiles/)) does not match what most any other package uses for quartiles, although given the many ways of calculating them it's hard to call it "wrong". The documentation can be taken to task for not even attempting to describe the logic, though.

Comment: Note that `QUARTILE.EXC` just changes the method to N+1 interpolation, which is used by more packages, but arguably still not the most common way to calculate quartiles. As no single method is "correct", you'll have to decide what's most important for your use case -- Excel's result may be "good enough", but if you have to match what some other method produces, replacement formulas are likely needed.